# C# scanning image code improvement

Tags: c#, performance, image-processing

I'm working on a screen sharing app, which runs a loop and grab fast screenshots using GDI methods . [example here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/perrylee/screencapture11142005234547pm/screencapture.aspx)

Of course I also use a flood fill algorithm to find the changes areas between 2 images (previous screenshot and current).

I use another small trick - I downscale the snapshot resolution in 10, because processing 1920*1080=2073600 pixels very constantly is not very efficient.

However when I find the rectangle bounds - I apply it on the original full size bitmap and I just multiply by 10 the dimension (including top, left, width, height).

This is the scanning code:

```
    unsafe bool ArePixelsEqual(byte* p1, byte* p2, int bytesPerPixel)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesPerPixel; ++i)
            if (p1[i] != p2[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    private unsafe List<Rectangle> CodeImage(Bitmap bmp, Bitmap bmp2)
    {
       List<Rectangle> rec = new List<Rectangle>();
        var bmData1 = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        var bmData2 = bmp2.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);

        int bytesPerPixel = 4;
        IntPtr scan01 = bmData1.Scan0;
        IntPtr scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;
        int stride1 = bmData1.Stride;
        int stride2 = bmData2.Stride;
        int nWidth = bmp.Width;
        int nHeight = bmp.Height;
        bool[] visited = new bool[nWidth * nHeight];

        byte* base1 = (byte*)scan01.ToPointer();
        byte* base2 = (byte*)scan02.ToPointer();

        for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y ++)
        {
            byte* p1 = base1;
            byte* p2 = base2;

            for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; ++x)
            {
                if (!ArePixelsEqual(p1, p2, bytesPerPixel) && !(visited[x + nWidth * y]))
                {
                    // fill the different area
                    int minX = x;
                    int maxX = x;
                    int minY = y;
                    int maxY = y;

                    var pt = new Point(x, y);

                    Stack<Point> toBeProcessed = new Stack<Point>();
                    visited[x + nWidth * y] = true;
                    toBeProcessed.Push(pt);
                    while (toBeProcessed.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var process = toBeProcessed.Pop();
                        var ptr1 = (byte*)scan01.ToPointer() + process.Y * stride1 + process.X * bytesPerPixel;
                        var ptr2 = (byte*)scan02.ToPointer() + process.Y * stride2 + process.X * bytesPerPixel;
                        //Check pixel equality
                        if (ArePixelsEqual(ptr1, ptr2, bytesPerPixel))
                            continue;

                        //This pixel is different
                        //Update the rectangle
                        if (process.X < minX) minX = process.X;
                        if (process.X > maxX) maxX = process.X;
                        if (process.Y < minY) minY = process.Y;
                        if (process.Y > maxY) maxY = process.Y;

                        Point n; int idx;
                        //Put neighbors in stack
                        if (process.X - 1 >= 0)
                        {
                            n = new Point(process.X - 1, process.Y); idx = n.X + nWidth * n.Y;
                            if (!visited[idx]) { visited[idx] = true; toBeProcessed.Push(n); }
                        }

                        if (process.X + 1 < nWidth)
                        {
                            n = new Point(process.X + 1, process.Y); idx = n.X + nWidth * n.Y;
                            if (!visited[idx]) { visited[idx] = true; toBeProcessed.Push(n); }
                        }

                        if (process.Y - 1 >= 0)
                        {
                            n = new Point(process.X, process.Y - 1); idx = n.X + nWidth * n.Y;
                            if (!visited[idx]) { visited[idx] = true; toBeProcessed.Push(n); }
                        }

                        if (process.Y + 1 < nHeight)
                        {
                            n = new Point(process.X, process.Y + 1); idx = n.X + nWidth * n.Y;
                            if (!visited[idx]) { visited[idx] = true; toBeProcessed.Push(n); }
                        }
                    }

                       //finaly set a rectangle.
                             Rectangle r = new Rectangle(minX * 10, minY * 10, (maxX - minX + 1) * 10, (maxY - minY + 1) * 10);
                            rec.Add(r);

                            //got the rectangle now i'll do whatever i want with that.
                            //notify i scaled everything by x10 becuse i want to apply the changes on the originl 1920x1080 image.

                }

            p1 += bytesPerPixel;
            p2 += bytesPerPixel;
        }

        base1 += stride1;
        base2 += stride2;
    }


        bmp.UnlockBits(bmData1);
        bmp2.UnlockBits(bmData2);

        return rec;
    }
```

This is my call:

```
  private void Start()
  {     
     full1 = GetDesktopImage();//the first,intial screen.

     while (true)
     {
         full2 = GetDesktopImage();
         a = new Bitmap(full1, 192, 108);//resizing for faster processing the images.
         b = new Bitmap(full2, 192, 108);  // resizing for faster processing the images.
         CodeImage(a, b);

         count++;          // counter for the performance.
         full1 = full2;    // assign old to current bitmap.
      }
    }
```

However, after all the tricks and techniques I used, the algorithm runs quite slow... on my machine - Intel i5 4670k 3.4ghz - it runs only 20 times (at the maximum! It might get lower)! It maybe sounds fast (don't forget I have to send each changed area over the network after), but I'm looking to achieve more processed image per second. I think the main bottleneck is in the resizing of the 2 images - but I just thought it would be even faster after resizing - because it would have to loop through less pixels... **192*108=200,000** only..

I would appreciate any help, any improvement. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just stream through a video encoder?

Comment: @RogerRowland but i have to send snapshots over the netowork.. so mjpeg or anything else cant realy help...

Comment: No need to create 2 bitmaps every time. `b` becomes `a` in the next iteration since `b` is `full2` scaled and `full1 = full2`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp but i need always to scale the 2 last and current bitmaps... maybe i didnt got you 100%?

Comment: Have you done any performance testing? What's the overhead of sending full frames? How long does it take compared to your algorithm? A cheap and simple trick might be to just create a difference image (i.e. this image minus last image), which will be quick to compute and may have lots of zero pixels where there's no change, then just compress (zip) before sending and reconstruct at the other end. With all of these things, it's important to make actual timings rather than guess what will be more efficient.

Comment: @RogerRowland i do measured the time.... i wrote above.. it's running usually at 20 times in second(means it processing 2 frames 20 times). what do you mean creating a difference picture? which will contain many transparent pixels? tried it already... hugee network usage... tons of byte even after compression.. if you think your solution might be good don't be afraid to post it.. XD i will happily accept any thing which could help!